# Image not loading in Django application

Tags: django

models.py have below row

```
image1 = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='post_pics')
```

settings.py as follow

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

in template I load static files

```
`{% load static %}`   {% for post in posts %}
   
        <img  src={{ post.image1 }} >
      
    {% endfor %}
```

But still resulting in no image found

Comment: <img  src={{ post.image1.url }} >

Comment: use ` <img  src={{ post.image1.url }} >`

Answer (score 0):

use `<img src={{ post.image1.url }} >`